# how to use unicode blockelements in C?

Tags: c, unicode, escaping

I want to use unicode blocks in my C program to display them in the console like ▇, ░ and so on. However, whenever I try to use the escape sequence for unicode characters, I only get weird letters like:

```
printf("/u259A"); //259A is the unicode for ▚
Output: ÔûÜ
```

I looked up how to include unicode charactes then tried to use wchar_t:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wchar_t c = "\u259A";
  printf("%c",c);
  return 0;
}
```

but that only gave me `☺` as the output instead of ▚. Removing `setlocale()` would give me a blank output. I dont know what do to from this point on. The only thing I saw was using `printf("\xB2");` which gave you `▓`. But I dont understand where the `B2` comes from or what it stands for.

Comment: [Take a look at this](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html) and then try searching for "unicode & c" or something like that.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape

Comment: I think your question has a typo: Did you use `"\u259A"` right? with Backslash? In any case, print to a file. If it is ok, try to check if your console/terminal support UTF-8 (and font). Do not use `wchar_t` with UTF-8 (it will just confuse things, and you just mixed wchar_t with char in the `printf`. So ignore wchar_t as just a temporary obsolete solution (but if you are really using UCS-2)

Comment: Simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (examples in Python): `"\u259A".encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp850')` returns `'ÔûÜ'` and `"▓".encode( 'cp850')` returns `b'\xb2'`. Note that `"▓" == "\u2593"` is `true`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked for me was the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
  wprintf(L"\x2590 \x2554 \x258c \x2592"); //Output : ▐ ╔ ▌ ▒
  return 0;
}
```

the function `_setmode()` is apparently for setting the console on u16 text encoding. `wprintf()` allows you to print wide characters (unicode aswell). The `L""` before the string indicates to the compiler, that the following string is a unicode string. Thanks to everyone for their time and answers!